# How to transform a dataframe to a dictionary with key tuples

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

how can I convert a dataframe to a dictionary with the keys as a tuple?

```
    0            1             2                
0   0           4733          456           
1   5223        0             5680          
2   901         5635          0
```

like this:

```
i!=j

{(0, 1): 4733,
 (0, 2): 456,
 (1, 0): 5223,
 (1, 2): 5680,
 (2, 0): 901,
 (2, 1): 5635
}
```

Comment: a dataframe sorry!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `stack()` and `to_dict()`

```
df.stack().to_dict()
```

Output:

```
{(0, '0'): 0,
 (0, '1'): 4733,
 (0, '2'): 456,
 (1, '0'): 5223,
 (1, '1'): 0,
 (1, '2'): 5680,
 (2, '0'): 901,
 (2, '1'): 5635,
 (2, '2'): 0}
```

It appears that tuples with the same values should be excluded. If this is the case the below should work:

```
df.where(df.ne(0)).stack().to_dict()
```

or

```
{(i,c):v for (i,c),v in df.stack().to_dict().items() if int(i) != int(c)}
```

Output:

```
{(0, '1'): 4733,
 (0, '2'): 456,
 (1, '0'): 5223,
 (1, '2'): 5680,
 (2, '0'): 901,
 (2, '1'): 5635}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({0: [0, 5223, 901], 1: [4733, 0, 5635], 2: [456, 5680, 0]})

result = {}
for k, v in df.to_dict(orient='list').items():
    for idx, value in enumerate(v):
        if k != idx:
            result[(idx, k)] = value
print(result)
```

**Output:**

```
{
    (1, 0): 5223, 
    (2, 0): 901, 
    (0, 1): 4733, 
    (2, 1): 5635, 
    (0, 2): 456, 
    (1, 2): 5680
}
```